# Spring Boot app in Docker container not starting in Cloud Run after building successfully - cannot access jarfile

Tags: spring-boot, docker, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I've set up continuous deployment to Cloud Run from GitHub for my Spring Boot project, and while it's successfully building in Cloud Build, when I go over to Cloud Run, I get the following error under Creating Revision:
`The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable.`

When I go over to the Logs, I see the following errors:

```
2022-09-23 09:42:47.881 BST
Error: Unable to access jarfile /app/target/educity-manager-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

{
insertId: "632d7187000d739d29eb84ad"
labels: {5}
logName: "projects/educity-manager/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr"
receiveTimestamp: "2022-09-23T08:42:47.883252595Z"
resource: {2}
textPayload: "Error: Unable to access jarfile /app/target/educity-manager-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
timestamp: "2022-09-23T08:42:47.881565Z"
}



2022-09-23 09:43:48.800 BST
run.googleapis.com
…ager/revisions/educity-manager-00011-fod
Ready condition status changed to False for Revision educity-manager-00011-fod with message: Deploying Revision.

{
insertId: "w6ptr6d20ve"
logName: "projects/educity-manager/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fsystem_event"
protoPayload: {
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"
resourceName: "namespaces/educity-manager/revisions/educity-manager-00011-fod"
response: {6}
serviceName: "run.googleapis.com"
status: {2}}
receiveTimestamp: "2022-09-23T08:43:49.631015104Z"
resource: {2}
severity: "ERROR"
timestamp: "2022-09-23T08:43:48.800371Z"
}
```

Dockerfile is as follows (and looking at the build log all of the commands in it completed successfully):

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
USER spring:spring
COPY . /app
ENTRYPOINT [ "java","-jar","/app/target/educity-manager-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" ]
```

I've read that Cloud Run defaults to exposing Port 8080, but just to be on the safe side I've put `server.port=${PORT:8080}` in my application.properties file (but it seems to make no difference one way or the other).

Comment: Were you able to start the container locally?

Comment: I tried following the [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local) for testing the container locally, but for reasons I couldn't work out the beta code dev environment wouldn't start - it would load part of the way and then freeze until it gave me a timeout error message. I did a `gcloud components update` but it didn't help...

Comment: I tried running the image from the Run button in Docker, but it failed to run there because it couldn't access the Cloud SQL server (and I haven't been able to get Google's SQL Proxy authorisation to work on my computer thanks to Windows Smartscreen stuff beyond my control), so I figured I'd have to try running it from Cloud Run so I could bypass the whole proxy issue...

Comment: Start a VM with a COS OS and test in the cloud instead

Comment: Have just tried setting up a Kubernetes cluster and passing the container image to it, but much like the Cloud Run approach it's just in a crash loop and the logs are just saying `Error: Unable to access jarfile /app/target/educity-manager-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: You have an issue in your container creation. That's why it's more a software issue, than a cloud issue. use dive software (on github) to understand your container structure.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into similar issues in the past. Usually, I am able to resolve this issue by:

- specifying the port in the application itself (as you indicated in your post), and
- [exposing the required port in my dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) eg. `EXPOSE 8080`

Comment: Just tried adding EXPOSE 8080 but to no avail I'm afraid...

Answer (score 0):

Oh my good god I have done it. After two full days of digging, I realised that because I was doing it through github, my .gitignore file was excluding the /target folder containing the jar file, so Cloud Build never got the jar file mentioned in the Dockerfile.

I am going to have a cry and then go to the pub.